# Ajax Post with php in jtable is returning empty data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I've been struggling with this and I don't find anyway to get this right.
I am using jtable and the thing is everything works correctly except with child elements.

I added a child table to a button so that when it opens it displays data related with the previous id.
The thing is listAction, updateAction and createAction are working okay, but when it comes to deleteAction it is not sending any information via post, so there is no way I can delete the exact row I want to.
This is the jquery (jtable) code:

```
          asignaturas: {
            title: '',
            width: '5%',
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            display: function (asignaData) {
                //Create an image that will be used to open child table
                var $img = $('<img src="metro/list_metro.png" style="opacity:0.4;"title="Editar Asignaturas" />');
                //Open child table when user clicks the image
                $img.click(function () {

                    $('#crudTable').jtable('openChildTable',
                            $img.closest('tr'),
                            {
                                title: asignaData.record.nombre + ' - Assignatures',

                                actions: {
                                    listAction: 'index.php?ex=jprofesor&action=prepara&prepara=list&id=' + asignaData.record.dni,


                                   deleteAction: 'index.php?ex=jprofesor&action=prepara&prepara=delete&id=' + asignaData.record.dni,
                                    updateAction: 'index.php?ex=jprofesor&action=prepara&prepara=update&id=' + asignaData.record.dni,

                                                createAction: function (postData) {
                //console.log("creating from custom function...");
            return $.Deferred(function ($dfd) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?ex=jprofesor&action=prepara&prepara=create&id=' + asignaData.record.dni,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: postData,
                    success: function (data) {

                        $dfd.resolve(data);

                        $('#crudTable').jtable('reload');
                        $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $dfd.reject();
                    }
                });
            });
        }


                                },
                                fields: {
                                    dni: {
                                        type: 'hidden',
                                        defaultValue: asignaData.record.dni
                                    },
                                    codigo: {

                                       title: 'Asignatura',
                                        width: '80%',
                                      // list: false,
                                         options: "index.php?ex=jprofesor&action=prepara&prepara=asignaturas"

                                    }
                                }
                            }, function (data) { //opened handler
                                data.childTable.jtable('load');
                            });
                });
                //Return image to show on the person row
                return $img;
            }

        //acaba child


        }
    },
```

And this is the php code that deletes:

```
    $query = $query." and p.dni = '".$dni."'";
        $dni = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $codigo = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['codigo']);
        $conn->query("delete from prepara where dni = '".$dni."' and asignatura = '".$codigo."'");
        retornarPrepara($conn, $query);

function retornarPrepara($conn, $query, ) {
$rs = $conn->query($query);

$num_rows = $rs->num_rows;
$rows = array();
if($rs) {
        while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
        {   
            $rows[] = $row;

        }
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
    $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $num_rows;
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}

}
```

As far as I know the code is okay, but there must be something I'm missing in jquery to send the field codigo via post, but I thought jtable did this automatically as it is doing it with the parent jtable without any problem.

Comment: Have you looked in the console for errors?

Comment: yes but not any error appear, I am using the latest jtable version 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna answer my question as I finally got this to work... it was a silly mistake but at the same time it is good to be aware about it.
The thing is this a school exercise in which we received some database tables that don't have id's so I wasn't really treating the fields as if there was a primary key, anyway deleteAction only sends the key in ajax post so the only way to get it is putting key:true, into the field you want to get.
Once I added key:true, everything worked correctly.